# Windows Server 2012 - Domain Controller with internet domain

Tags: windows

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 and i wanted to use RemoteApps. For this I need to join a Domain. I don't have any Domain, so I wanted to create my own on the Win Server.

I tried for hours, reinstalled it often.. But nothing works.

Its a Virtualised Win Server, with ONE single, public IP.
Also I have a subdomain to this IP, windows.xxx.com

Any Ideas? 
I tried many tutorials Step-by-Step but they are all for lokal domain controllers..

Comment: Have you tried putting "Setting up a domain controller on Windows Server 2012" into Google? I found lots of guides, including a couple from Microsoft Technet.

Comment: Yes i did.. But they are all nearby the same.

Comment: I mean, i tried "windows server 2012 Domain Controller" and similar stuff, but that gets the same results

Comment: Can you update your answer to include more details as to what you have tried so far and any pitfalls you have come across. From this point people can start giving you specific answers, as you aren't going to get a step-by-step guide to configuring a domain controller here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Microsoft Technet Library you can find detailed (step-by-step) guides for many Microsoft products incl. Windows Server 2008 R2, 2012, 2012 R2. I'm sure the documentation for the future versions will be published also.

Here is the link  to **Install Active Directory Domain Services** (Applies To: Windows Server 2012, Windows Server 2012 R2) guide: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh472162.aspx

Comment: While the link might provide an answer it can quickly become outdated. Please include the main points from the link in you answer and use the link as a reference. Thanks